# Personal VBA code Workbook - BeforeClose event across all/any open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event in my `PERSONAL.XLSB` that I would like to apply to all/any open workbooks.

The code is designed to look for a specific string of text in the workbook title and flag a message box if the string of text is found.

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim pos As Integer
Dim iRet As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String

' Test
pos = InStr(ThisWorkbook.Name, "<Insert String here>")

If pos <> 0 Then

    ' Prompt
    strPrompt = "<Message>"

    ' Dialog's Title
    strTitle = "<Title>"

    ' Display MessageBox
    iRet = MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)

    ' Check pressed button
    If iRet = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    Else
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

I appreciate that because this macro lies within my `PERSONAL.XLSB` workbook that it applies solely to itself only.

I am looking for a solution where a personal before close macro could apply to all/any open workbooks that do not themselves contain macros.

Comment: One somewhat complicated solution that I can think of involves keeping a specific "Master" workbook open at all times, putting in a timer that searches for other open workbooks and then linking a WithEvents workbook variable in the Master workbook to the other open workbooks.  This way you can catch the events in the other workbooks.  This is somewhat complicated to implement however.  Is this the type of solution you're looking for?

Comment: @OpiesDad I can see the potential in this solution, however I will be rolling this code out for other people to use and the thought of having a hidden master workbook open in the background of other users' computers strikes me with an element of instability/unpredictability?..

Comment: You need the "Personal.xlsb" workbook open either way?!  Won't the users need to have SOME workbook open?  nbayly's solution is a simplified version of what I was talking about, but again, it needs to be in an open workbook.  Their solution does not consider whether the users may open a different excel file in a different instance of Excel.  If they only open things in the SAME instance of Excel, it would work.  See comment on their answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by trapping the Application event rather than the Workbook event.

Source: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/488682-automatically-run-workbook-event-workbook-open.html

```
Private WithEvents AppEvents As Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set AppEvents = Application

End Sub

Private Sub AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    If Not Wb Is Me Then
        Call YourMacro(Wb)
    End If

End Sub
```

Just encapsulate your code in a Sub and call it where "YourMacro" is indicated.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How does this work in conjunction with a 'Workbook_BeforeClose' event?

Comment: As mentioned in my other comment, this will only work if the user's open all excel files in the same instance of Excel.  @Mr. J, this code will give you the events in the application for ANY workbook, but it only uses Application level events.  I haven't done this, but in research I found this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_workbookbeforecloseeventhandler.aspx that should help in setting up the workbook_beforeclose event on the application level.

Comment: @OpiesDad wouldn't other instances of Excel still be using the same `Personal.xlsb` template and hence have the VBA code active on any and all instances of Excel? @Mr. J my apologies as I missed changing the event from the source code. You would not call it from the `Workbook_BeforeClose` but rather from `AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler` event that OpiesDad kindly provided. I will correct my answer for future reference.

Comment: If you double-click on an Excel file, it will generally either open Excel if you don't have it open already or it will open the workbook using the open instance of Excel.  If instead, while you already have Excel open, you click on the Excel icon to open another instance of Excel, then use Open file from the menu, you now have TWO open Excel instances (applications).  This code will only look at the one that your Personal.xlsb file is open in and will not run in any files open in the other Excel instances.

Comment: @nbayly I'm not sure the Workbookbeforecloseeventhandler works that way.  If you read the documentation, it looks like it's more complicated than that....you will need to create a Delegate Sub.  I am not familiar with this and didn't really have time to play with it to figure out exactly how it works, so thought providing the documentation would at least help.

Comment: My understanding is that **each** instance of Excel opens its own copy of `Personal.xlsb` automatically. There might be issues if the document is not set to be shared but seems those are fixable. And though the scope of each `Personal.xlsb` is walled by its Excel instance, as each instance has it's own version running you are still covering your requirements.

Comment: I have not tested that event in particular but when setting the `Application` object to pass events to the AppEvents variable per `WithEvents` option, all regular events that pre-built objects (ie `ThisWorkbook`) have can also be triggered for application events. Hence `AppEvents_WorkbookBeforeCloseEventHandler` should work exactly as calling a `Workbook.BeforeClose` event. Full disclosure: I have not tested and basing just on online sources, please feel free to correct me. More info: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/appevent.aspx